# Web page displays in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Not I.E

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Perhaps someone can find the problem. I've tried everything I know. And I apologize if this has been addressed before. I found similar threads, but none that address this problem specifically.

If you visit [hiredimensions.net](http://hiredimensions.net) using Chrome, Firefox even Safari it will display properly. However, not so in I.E. (any version). It appears that it will not resolve the CSS background elements for the middle and lower part of the page. This site has been checked in W3C and is 100% compliant; no errors.

If you have any suggestions at all or need to look at the CSS please let me know. I'm stuck on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting .content to have the overflow:auto property setting? If you float an item inside a container, it will not go down all the way with the container(s) that are floated, without that property. Nice website by the way!

Comment: Make sure the HTML is validated.  IE hates invalid HTML.

Comment: @Sparky Has a good point!

Comment: Why are you forcing it into IE8 rendering mode? It works fine in IE9 with normal rendering.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine in IE9 for me, but I had to change the document mode to an IE9 version.  I assume this will work in IE10 as well, but I can't confirm.

I think the problem is that you are using HTML5, but it doesn't look like you are doing anything to support older browsers.  If you inspect the markup in IE8 or less, the section element with the content-bottom ID is empty; same with the article.  If you inspect the same element in Chrome, for instance, this is not the case and you will see that the article (and div) are in the section element.

EDIT: Check out this link, http://bit.ly/11D3Dyg; it has some options that will probably help.  Also like bažmegakapa said, trying using a different meta tag that will try to force the latest render mode.

Comment: +1 Got to the same point. It seems like he is loading the HTML5 shiv named html5.js, but it gives a 404. If the shiv is loaded, the HTML5 tags will work fine in IE8 and lower. Still advisable to let IE9 render the page normally though, IE8 mode is not a good idea...

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

It works in ie 10 for me. Hit f12 and go to the network tab. Reload the page you will see you have no /js/HTML5.js file.

I tried it in ie 7-9 as well and no issues.